# LINQ equivalent of std::partition

Tags: c#, linq, partitioning, stl-algorithm

What is a LINQ-based function that places all items which satisfy a predicate at the front of the sequence, like C++'s [`std::partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to achieve, a simpler solution would be [`OrderByDescending`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534855.aspx):

```
IEnumerable<T> Partition<T>(IEnumerable<T> s, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    return s.OrderByDescending(predicate);
}
```

This works because [`bool`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.aspx) implements [`IComparable<bool>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx) with `false` coming before `true`. So items for which `predicate` evaluates to `true` will be placed first in the result set.

And here's a hand-made implementation, just in case you're interested. I haven't done any benchmarks but this one might actually be faster.<sup>1</sup>

```
IEnumerable<T> Partition<T>(IEnumerable<T> s, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    List<T> falses = new List<T>();
    foreach(var t in s) 
    {
        if (predicate(t)) 
        {
            yield return t;
        }
        else
        {
            falses.Add(t);
        }
    }

    foreach (var t in falses)
    {
        yield return t;
    }
}
```

<sup>1: The hand-made solution is O(*n*), but `OrderBy` is considered to be O(*n* log *n*). However, depending on the implementation details of the `OrderBy` method, they might perform nearly identically.</sup>

Comment: One minor thing is that the attempt provided by Matt Kline is evaluated eagerly whereas `OrderByDescending` would be deferred. I would definitely favour the `OrderByDescending` solution, but just so long as Matt is aware of this difference from his implementation.

Answer (score 0):

My best shot:

```
IEnumerable<T> Partition<T>(IEnumerable<T> s, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    var split = s.GroupBy(predicate);
    return split
        .Where(kv => kv.Key)
        .Single()
        .Concat(split
            .Where(kv => !kv.Key)
            .Single());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `SelectMany`, you can improve your own answer:

```
IEnumerable<T> Partition<T>(IEnumerable<T> s, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    return s.GroupBy(predicate).SelectMany(xs => xs);
}
```

Comment: This will group the items together, but it won't return the groups in any guaranteed order--if the first item evaluates to true, it will return all the true's first, if it evaluates to false, it will return all the false's first. You still need an `OrderBy` of some sort.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Thanks. It’s merely a complicated version of yours, then.